# Parse a string with a for loop, return individual characters

Tags: python, string

I am doing a parsing of a variable, which contains a string

```
a1
b2
c3
```

Now I want to get a1, b2 and c3, so I wrote a for loop

```
for items in string
    print items
```

this returns

```
a
1

b
2

c
3
```

How do I tell the for loop, that I want each value, instead than each character?

Comment: Are the strings on new line?

Comment: yes, there is a newline on each string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `split()` with no args to split on whitespace.

```
for items in string.split()
    print items
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method to split the string into individual lines:

```
>>> data = '''\
... a1
... b2
... c3
... '''
>>> for items in data.splitlines():
...     print items
...
a1
b2
c3
>>>
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer because string contains new lines, not whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

var = "a1b2c3"

for i in range(len(var)):

```
if var[i].isdigit():
    print var[i]
```

output

1

2

3

Comment: Not sure about this; I do not need just the number